# How do I format C# in VSC like with Prettier?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, prettier

I've been using Prettier during a time and with JavaScript works perfect.

But since I also started to work with C#, I don't know how to setup VSC for still use Prettier for JavaScript and another plugin for C# formatting.

Edit: if I disable Prettier as default editor it works. But I can't disable only for C#. This setting doesn't works:

`"prettier.disableLanguages": [ "csharp", "cs" ]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code doesn't format C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352611/visual-studio-code-doesnt-format-c-sharp-code)

Comment: @gunr2171 C# format is enabled.

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500433/auto-format-c-sharp-code-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: @gunr2171 I've format on save set to true in settings, and it works. But the problem is, if I use Prettier, it doesn't know about C#. If I don't use it, it says: "there is no csharp formatter installed".

Comment: Looking at the question maybe it's something related with OmniSharp. I will investigate, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

[CSharpier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csharpier.csharpier-vscode) is an awesome code formatter for C# inspired by Prettier!

To enable it:

1. Install the CSharpier VSCode extension
2. Open the control panel (Ctrl + Shift + P)
3. Go to Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)
4. Add this to your settings.json file

```json
  "[csharp]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "csharpier.csharpier-vscode" },
```

5. Navigate to a C# file, then look for a pop-up in the bottom right that asks to install it as a local or global tool. Once it appears, click either the "local" or "global" option to install it.

> Note: The tool part of the install is required since the Roslyn team [doesn't support alternative code formatters plugging into Omnisharp directly](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/2167), so instead this tool works alongside the VSCode extension to do formatting that way instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I found that CSharpier has really few options available.

Prettier can work fine with the official C# plugin by using `"editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-dotnettools.csharp"` in settings.json.

And you can create an `.editorconfig` file to customize your options. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-style-rule-options?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

Instead of have Prettier as default formatter, and disable it only for C#, I had to enable Prettier only for the languages that I want.

`"[javascript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" },`

In this way, if it's not a JS file, it will use the VSC integrated formatter.

I don't know why I can't just disable Prettier for C#, but it's a solution for this problem.