# Personal Autoformat (Visual Studio C# / git)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autoformatting

I have 2 different settings in visual studio, my personal and our company guidelines and a git repository where code should be commited with our company guidelines. Is it possible to automatically autoformat the code on opening the file with my personal settings? Then, when I finished working (either on save or preferably on git pre-commit) I would like to autoformat the files I worked on with our company guidelines.

Is there a way to achieve this?

EDIT: Language is C#.

Comment: Depends on the language being used. Git does not care about these things

Comment: The language is C#.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500433/auto-format-c-sharp-code-in-visual-studio-code